# Error parsing POM File using Maven in Jenkins

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, jenkins

So I've been trying to run my Selenium tests using Jenkins.
I created a Maven project, and set the correct POM.xlm pathfile (At least it's what I'm almost certain)
And I continue to get an error at parsing the POM file saying the file is not present in the file path.
The project does work if maven run it from console or eclipse ide.

Here's the stacktrace of the error given by Jenknins.

```
Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Pagode
Parsing POMs
Discovered a new module com.hugomonteiro:PagodeAutomatedTests PagodeAutomatedTests
Modules changed, recalculating dependency graph
Established TCP socket on 50661
[PagodeAutomatedTests] $ /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -cp /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-agent-1.12-alpha-1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.4/libexec/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.4/libexec/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.4/libexec /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-3.25.jar /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-interceptor-1.12-alpha-1.jar /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.12-alpha-1.jar 50661
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f /Users/hugomonteiro/eclipse-workspace/PagodeAutomatedTests/pom.xml test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[HUDSON] Collecting dependencies info
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------< com.hugomonteiro:PagodeAutomatedTests >----------------
[INFO] Building PagodeAutomatedTests 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.testng:testng:jar:5.14.3 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.66 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ PagodeAutomatedTests ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ PagodeAutomatedTests ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ PagodeAutomatedTests ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ PagodeAutomatedTests ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ PagodeAutomatedTests ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/hugomonteiro/eclipse-workspace/PagodeAutomatedTests/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Starting ChromeDriver 2.42.591059 (a3d9684d10d61aa0c45f6723b327283be1ebaad8) on port 21561
Only local connections are allowed.
Oct 12, 2018 5:26:39 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 15.043 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
doLoginTest(testcases.LoginTest)  Time elapsed: 10.681 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of [[ChromeDriver: chrome on MAC (6cf1ac936bdb4be38c29d55651ee5c6b)] -> css selector: [class='fa fa-fw fa-caret-down']] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'Hugos-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:858:ef39:e614:659a%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.42.591059 (a3d9684d10d61a..., userDataDir: /var/folders/9l/55xyqdlx7gl...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:50670}, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 69.0.3497.100, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: 6cf1ac936bdb4be38c29d55651ee5c6b
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:283)
    at pages.actions.LoginActions.selectLanguage(LoginActions.java:40)
    at pages.actions.LoginActions.doLogin(LoginActions.java:26)
    at testcases.LoginTest.doLoginTest(LoginTest.java:21)

Results :

Failed tests: 
  LoginTest.doLoginTest:21 » Timeout Expected condition failed: waiting for visi...

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[JENKINS] Recording test results
[WARNING] Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class hudson.maven.reporters.SurefireArchiver$2; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/
[WARNING] Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class hudson.maven.reporters.MavenArtifactArchiver$2; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/
[WARNING] Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class org.jfrog.hudson.maven2.MavenDependenciesRecorder$1; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/
[WARNING] Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class hudson.maven.reporters.MavenFingerprinter$1; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 20.760 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-12T17:26:54+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project PagodeAutomatedTests: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/hugomonteiro/eclipse-workspace/PagodeAutomatedTests/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[JENKINS] Archiving /Users/hugomonteiro/eclipse-workspace/PagodeAutomatedTests/pom.xml to com.hugomonteiro/PagodeAutomatedTests/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/PagodeAutomatedTests-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
/Users/hugomonteiro/eclipse-workspace/PagodeAutomatedTests/pom.xml is not inside /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Pagode/Users/hugomonteiro/eclipse-workspace/PagodeAutomatedTests/; will archive in a separate pass
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Pagode/Users/hugomonteiro/eclipse-workspace/PagodeAutomatedTests/pom.xml
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
    at hudson.FilePath.read(FilePath.java:1973)
    at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.properties.PomPropertiesFinder.findProperties(PomPropertiesFinder.java:50)
    at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.MavenInfoExtractor.extract(MavenInfoExtractor.java:58)
    at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.MavenInfoEnvironment.tearDown(MavenInfoEnvironment.java:42)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:908)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1819)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any help would be excelent.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: The fact that I'm seeing `eclipse-workspace` on your CI server is a big red flag.

Comment: I'm new to using Jenkins, what should be there?

Comment: Generally something like `/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Pagode/pom.xml`. It looks like you have hard-coded paths somewhere in your configuration (potentially POM or Jenkins job setup) that shouldn't be.

Comment: Oh right ! I needed to put the folder in jenkins workspace ! Now it is working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem was :
I was hardcoding the pom file from the eclipse workspace directly to the Jenkins pom file path and this is wrong.

How I fixed with chrylis help :
Moved the project folder to the Jenkins workspace and gave the path from that directory and it worked just fine.

Comment: That's not really a good approach; ideally, you should be using version control, and Jenkins should be making its own clean copy. The project shouldn't depend on the exact location where it's checked out.

Comment: But how do use a version control when the projects are local? I know this aproach can be done using git, just not sure if I can do it with local projects... Thanks again for the feedback!